# How to bypass captchas from youtube? let the users fill it

Tags: node.js, ajax, recaptcha, captcha

I am using youtube-dl to download videos from youtube,now I have reached my limits and then youtube is showing me captchas i want to send these captchas to user to fill them and download videos. How can solve this problem ?